# Repeate filled cells of a row for x times in another row in Goolge Sheets by formula

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have a column containing x rows of names and I want to be able to repeat those rows of names x times each in another row.

It should be possilbe to have at least 15 names and repeate it 900 times.

Here an example:

[image: Example]

I tried this now for about 6 hour with arrayformula etc. and didn't find any working solution..

For example =TRANSPOSE(split(rept(join(";",A:A)&";",10),";")) would do the job, but the rept function is limited in characters, so it doesn't work for this case..

Are you able to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with REDUCE and SEQUENCE like this. It's wrapped in QUERY to exclude empty rows, so you can get your full column as input, despite its amount of elements:

```
=QUERY(REDUCE(,SEQUENCE(A1),LAMBDA(a,v,{a;B1:B})),"Where Col1 is not null")
```

[image]

Comment: Woooow, this is wonderful!

Answer (score -1):

use:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(TEXT(TRANSPOSE(A1:A4); FLATTEN(SPLIT(REPT("@×"; 5); "×")))))
```